# What networking components do I need for building a WLAN in a building?

Tags: networking, router, switch, gateway

I am doing a project where I have to provide wifi coverage in a shopping mall.

I am planning to spread several routers across the mall to cover the whole area. My question is what kind of components such as switches/gateways will I need?

The internet data will come from a certain origin point in the mall. All the Ethernet cables will go from that point to each of the routers. I want each router to receive the full throughput from each cable so the routers will only be connected to that origin point and won't be connected between each other.

SWITCH:

I know that Switches allow to connect various devices to each other but, in this case, since I don't need the routers to connect between each other, I don't need a switch, right?

GATEWAY:

Will I need a gateway at the origin point because of the different internet protocols between the Ethernet network and the ISP network (or are the protocols the same)?

Comment: This question is not [on topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) on Super User. It's probably better suited for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Routers do not provide wireless access. They route. I suspect you meant 'multi-function consumer devices which combine switch, WAP, router, firewall, ...'. Which is not what you want to use. For wide access you want pure Wireless Access Points (WAPs) or one single professional device with multiple attached radio's.

Comment: @Hennes But can't routers be used as access points too and provide wireless access?
Actually in this situation, since I'm not connecting the routers to any other router except the origin point, I can use access points instead of routers, right?

Comment: They can, but if you use the thing called router (which is not just a router) as WAP then you also want to worry about their other functions. E.g preventing multiple NAT, caring about DHCP services etc.  And with multiple devices in the 2.4GHz band you also want to carefully select the used channels and turn transmit power way down (yes, down, not up).

Comment: @Hennes Thanks :) So using WAP is way simpler since I will only have to worry about choosing the right channels for each of them so that there's no interference?

Comment: Tried to post it as an answer so I could use markup. However as the last sentence in the answer: The proper solution depends on a lot of things I do not yet know.

Comment: You can use consumer multi-function wireless devices, but you can also use a ball peen hammer to frame a house: That doesn't mean you're doing it right, and there will be problems. Unfortunately, budgetary concerns means you're likely to be stuck hanging a bunch of cheap devices up and it'll work for people who like steal others private info, and then it'll break. For the real job you should expect to pay a few thousand bucks for a controller, and several thousand for a pile of WAPs and use one of the roaming protocols to get it all to work together nicely.

Comment: Aye. If you budget is big enough then a Cisco 5760 Wireless Controller or similar will do wonders. If not use SoHo stuff and spent lots of hours tweaking. The price of a proper controller might lead to the homebrewn solutions though.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

One simple modem facing ISP side and then fanning out to multiple 'routers' will work as long as each 'router' has its own DPCP range.

```
                                                         ----  'router 1'
                                 router with             |
 ISP  --- Modem --- firewall --- DHCP server --- switch -+---  'router 2'
                                                         |
                                                         ----  'router 3'
```

(all devices mentioned here between the ISP and the branching out of the Ethernet cables are often in one physical device, which incorrectly gets marketed as a 'router').

Long answer:

Wireless is tricky. Especially if you need to cater to the 2.4GHz band. There are 13 channels in that band which may be used for wireless networking. However only three channels can be used without overlap.

That means you will have to plan which channel to use and where to use it.

Example or a large area layout in 2D:

```
Graph of 5 access points in a large room.
No identical channels next to each other.



Channel 1                                 channel 13

                      channel 6

channel 13                                channel 1
```

You want to make a similar map for the whole area. In 3D, and adjust for walls. This is not entirely trivial and there are firms whose job is to set up just such a network for conferences.

Also, for the 2.4GHz band you want to turn the transmit power down and have as many small cells as possible. And since water (and humans are mostly water) is a good blocker for 2.4GHz radiation you want as few humans as possible between your transmitters and the receiving devices.

Translated: Often mount your radio's or 'routers' on the ceiling.

Note that there are several professional firms selling what essentially is one Wireless access point with a dedicated controller unit and dedicated radios.  These things are not cheap, but work very well and add nice features in case of HW failure.

Second note: This layout with limited channel is for 2.4GHz. the 5GHz band does not have this problem. If you do not need to cater for every possible devices (but e.g. only for specific scanners with wireless interface) then do not provide 2.4GHz at all.

---

Ok, almost at the point where we can start the answer. :)

First question fior that: Do the different shops each have their own protection? If so the network would look more like this:

```
                            ----  shop 1 firewall -- shop 1 'routers'
                            |
 ISP  --- Mdm - fw- switch -+---  shop 2 firewall -- shop 2 'routers'
                            |
                            ----  shop 3 firewall -- shop 3 'routers'
```

Each shop would have its own network range (probably provided by DHCP on its own router). The main Modem/fw/switch/router would have routers to each of there. Preferably with static IP addresses.

You will need to maintain all of these (not much work, just a monthly check of logs and firmware updates. If you give them all the same brand/ and model then there is not much work here, but you do want to make sure that your devices are up to date and not vulnerable to malware.

You might also want to think about IPv6 (which is now many decades old and highly preferred over legacy IPv4).

With a professional solution however your setup would look like this:

```
                                       +----------------Radio 1
                                       |
                                       |       -------- Radio 2
                                       |       |
 ISP  --- Modem --- firewall --- Wireless controller--- Radio 3
                                       |       |
                                       |       -------- Radio 4
                                       |
                                       +----------------Radio 5
```

Much cleaner. And if one of the radio's fails the controller will automatically adjust.

---

All of this ignores a few questions: Such as

1. Who is this network intended for?
2. How do people authenticate? (free guest network? WPA2/radius? A captive portal and all those disadvantages?)
3. How importent is wireless (A mere convenience vs a hard need for shopping transactions). In the last case case you want redundancy.
4. Who will maintain this and who is responsible?
5. Any filtering needed? (e.g. all bandwdth use up by one person who brought his/her personal laptop with a torrent client sill running).

And probably a few more questions which I forgot. All of which might yield a different answer.